# Trouble backing up Outlook .OST Files

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I need to copy .ost file when Outlook is open.

I found here:

https://support.jungledisk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200812964-Trouble-backing-up-Outlook-OST-Files

*Microsoft explanation of this design decision:
Maintaining changes to .ost files within shadow copies is expensive in terms of space and I/O activity. The performance impact doesn’t occur during the image backup itself--the only extra work at backup time is backing up the .ost file as part of the image. Instead, the performance impact occurs during the ongoing, everyday I/O to the .ost file when Outlook is running. If the .ost changes were kept in shadow copies, then every time Outlook writes to the .ost file, the result is a copy-on-write I/O hit (2 writes, 1 read). Although we have worked to reduce the impact of copy-on-writes on shadow copies,  a heavily churned file like an .ost file could still cause problems. For these reasons, and the fact that **.ost files can be regenerated, we chose to delete .ost files from the shadow copy before the image is created**.
Even if the performance issues didn’t exist, there are situations where Exchange will, after an .ost is restored, detect a “future” version of the .ost file and force you to delete and then regenerate the local .ost file. Therefore, it’s still preferable to regenerate an .ost file instead of restoring it.*

So, I can't create shadow copy of .OST file and I can't copy it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends on **why** you need to create a copy of an OST file. It can never be used standalone - it is only useable in the profile used to create it. It cannot be copied to another machine, and it cannot be used in a differ profile on the same machine. MSEMS provider recreates the OST file if it is missing. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this behavior:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToSnapshot

Comment: Format your answer